# FB Count Discrepancy (I already used the debugger and the fbrefresh param!)

Tags: debugging, facebook-sharer

http://m.lifetrac.ca/blog/how-choose-church - has 13 (you can visit in your mobile phone or add ?device=mobile) -- the full site (remove the m subdomain) says 0 Likes

I already debugged both links and they are fine. So I just don't know why they are different.
What makes it more strange is that other blog posts are fine! see 'impact-one' instead of 'how-choose-church'

Btw, I turned off mobile redirection that's why I was able to use the debugger. If you enter the mobile url now, it won't work. It seems that FB debugger is detected by the site as a desktop visitor therefore redirecting fb debugger to the full site -- I'm thinking that fb can't track 302 redirects.
...unless you put ?device=mobile -- then the debugger works.

sadly, i can't attach scrape info images :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all synced now. I just liked the post myself once and it's all consistent now!